# Refactoring C# event based with SQL Server operations

Tags: c#, sql-server, refactoring

I am not sure how to decide about how to refactor some production code. This code works as select records top 1 from db and decided to column containing value under the below.

```
switch(column_value):
   case send_email:
        send_email.DoIt();
   case enable_somexx:
        enable_somexx.DoIt();
   case response_email:
        response_email.DoIt();
```

Showing the below examples, there are created classes for every events (records) including a `DoIt()` method(SendMail, DecideMail, ResponseMail, MailXXX, enable_somexx). The classes include 3 subfolders actions named action, decision, response (actually these classes irrelevant which other because code select top 1 record)

I'm thinking of refactoring this code logic like this:

- Create base class named `Behaviour`
- other 3 main classes will inherit from this base class

Code:

```
public abstract Behaviour
{
     public virtual void DoIt(string type) {
     }
}

--Also another classes Decision, Response will inherit from Behaviour. 
public class Action : Behaviour
{
    override void DoIt(string type) {
    }
}

public class Email : Action 
{
    override void DoIt(string type)
    {
        if(type == SEND)
             call_sendmethod
        else if(xxx_operation_about_mail)
             call_xxx_operation_about_mail
    } 
}
```

But I cannot handle (actually I don't like my solution because I don't want to create same class every operations like EmailAction, EmailResponse, EmailDecision or another operations)

If you make this code block refactoring, how would you do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using your idea of refactoring ... this is how I would code it:

Here is an outline:

1. Create an abstract class for Behavior
2. Create an action class which inherits Behavior
3. Then you can code like this to trigger desire "action".
   Notice how I override the "Send" behavior to customize it to "special sent".

Here is the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/m3tjWl

> Blockquote

```
public class Program : Action
{
 public static void Main()
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    var command = Console.ReadLine();

    //trigger send from Action class
    Action x = new Action();
    x.DoIt(command);

    //trigger send from behavior class
    //the lines below are added to show how you can still access the parent behavior, remove or use where appropriate
    Behaviour y = x;
    y.Send();
 }
}

public abstract class  Behaviour 
{
    public virtual void Send()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sent");
    }

    public virtual void EnableX()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enabled");
    }

    public virtual void Reply()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("replied");
    }

    public abstract void DoIt(string type);
}

public class Action : Behaviour
{
 public override void DoIt(string type)
 {
    if(type.ToUpper() == "SEND")
        this.Send();
    else if (type.ToUpper() == "ENABLEX")
        this.EnableX();
    else if (type.ToUpper() == "REPLY")
        this.Reply();
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown Command");   
 }

 new public void Send()
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Special Sent");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your for reply,i'm away from my computer.I'm going to this solution,i think.